# Insert ACF custom field into comments WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, comments, hook

I created a shortcode like this:

```
function lijst_reacties(){
comments_template(); 
}
add_shortcode('reacties','lijst_reacties');
```

But it shows everything I need except that I need to add a custom field after the `author` name.
The custom field is called `beroepsfunctie`. How can I insert this one after the author name?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating your own comments template. The template should be called `comments.php` and exist in the root of your theme directory. This way when you call `comments_template();` it will pull from your custom template.

If you want to have multiple comments templates you can create another comments template and call the function as such `comments_template('comments-custom.php');`

Here is the link to the Comment Template section in the theme developers handbook https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/partial-and-miscellaneous-template-files/comment-template/